# Where to store dummy products images while developing Rails 4 website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I am working on my first RoR website. You can consider it as a shop with products.

I use Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, Cucumber for integration testing and RSpec for unit-testing. 
Also I use FactoryGirl for populating database with test data.
Apart of automatic testing I would like to be able to open website on local server and see some dummy products with description and images.

**Here is the question: where to store products images used in development environment?**

Here are my thoughts:

- I do not want to use paperclip yet.
- I cannot store dummy images in assets or public because they will be
  deployed to production.
- I do not know how to access /test/factories/images or any other
  directory except of assets and public.
- I do not want to store images in database.
- I want deployable solution in case I would need to populate test
  website from CI.

It seems to be a common Rails question: **where to store dummy test resources accessible to client?**
However the only solution I found is to use paperclip. But I do not have upload yet. I just want  to have 100 images for dummy products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cud use your db seed file for this and your tester should then only need to run `rake db:seed` to setup the dummy files.

If you create an directory inside `/db` and call it `seed_files` or something you prefer. Then in your `/db/seeds.rb` you cud write some code that moves those files into `/public/images/product_images`. `/public/images/product_images` should also be in git ignore.

When you do this you cud have an name pattern and anchor them to some product records in your database. You cud also put your seed script in an `unless Rails.env.production?` block if you will use your seed file in production but not seed the dummy images.

Comment: Tried that. I added images copying operation to my rake db:populate script. And hide images with gitignore. It works. But I am still hoping to get out-of-the-box solution without having to made this in rake task. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images in a subdirectory of `assets` such as `assets/dummy` and then add `assets/dummy` to the .gitignore file (assuming you're using git) so that the dummy directory is not deployable.

Comment: Interesting idea. However it doesn't cover deploying images to test webserver so that my tester could work with it

Comment: Then paperclip really is your best choice. It's easy to use.